# Should I allow duplicate content for getting backlinks?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, backlinks

I would like to know if having duplicate content on the web will affect a website's search engine presence.

My website has a blog. Some other websites have been asking for a permission to include my blog posts in their blogs with a link back to my website.

Surely getting a link back to my site is great for SEO. But is it a good strategy to allow duplicating content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate content is death for any/all site(s) without a canonical link back to your original content. I do not advise putting your content on other sites. With a canonical tag, it does nothing for the other site. Even then, I would not trust the other sites to create the canonical tag or not to remove it causing you problems down the road. It is always best to protect your interest. Remember that content is king. It is either death for both sites or a waste of time for one. This is a no bueno scenario.

Answer (score 2):

don't allow duplicate contents. Why? imagine a reader will read again what they have read on other site they have visited before.

Surely they will come to this scenario "I HAVE READ THIS SOMEWHERE ELSE" now confusion starts to build up pin pointing which one is legit and original.

**Authors Impact**
And if I am the one writing that content or the author and I found out someone copied my writings for the use of their own personal benefit I would feel bad, it's plagiarism.

**Search engine impact**
It will affect you hard...duplicate content are a big no even if you will rephrase it. Search engines are getting smarter now and can justify low quality content by their algorithm.

A good example is when it autocorrects your searches like DID YOU  MEAN "your query" so it exactly knows correct grammar and spelling.